# Fan always running

Tags: fan

I have an HP laptop pavilion dv619ca ( 8 GB RAM ; 64-bit ; i7 ; 256 GB HDD).
I installed the latest ubuntu 12.10 but the fan is always running and decreasing my battery life.
I need to know how to fix it please.
Thanks a million :D.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an HP laptop. I turned out the the graphic driver was unstable, therefore my graphical card became very hot with result that the fan was blowing very hard.

Install `lm-sensors` and check the temperature of your system with `sensors`. When youre CPU's arent very hot (below 80 degrees) you might have the same problem.

I 'solved' the problem by disabeling the graphical card and run on the Intel HD Graphics as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/support-drivers.html to try to find your model to see if there are any linux drivers for power management, I could not find your model.

I think this is a power management issue you need the proper drivers, either for the graphical card or other, unless there is no physical obstruction to cooling like keeping it on the cushion, sheets or similar. Unfortunately the info provided was not sufficient to find the model on the internet.